# Google Play Games - Leaderboard not displaying other players

Tags: android, google-play-services, leaderboard

Leaderboard created, published.
Other than myself, no other player is shown in my app's Leaderboard screen.
Friends (not beta testers) downloaded from store and played a bit. Again, only their profile is shown, in both Social and All tabs.
"Public Profile" is set for all my friends that used the game.
Tamper Protection from Google Play Games is Disabled.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You said that your published app does not show the leaderboard:

- even if there Profile is set to "public"
- Tamper protection is "Disabled"
- only their profile is shown in both "Social" and "All" tabs

Then I suggest to check this documentation, [Track progress with achievements, XP, and leaderboards](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3129939?hl=en&visit_id=636763930880961459-4102987082&rd=1).
You can also double check your gamer profile if it is in public to compare your scores to other gamers by [changing your privacy and other setting](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3129346).