# Google Play Games - "There are no public high score for this game"

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api

I created a leaderboard in google play console, and published it.
The authentication of the users success, it is not possible to see the public leaderboard scores.
[That's the message that appear on phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysms3.jpg).

Does anyone know how fix it and can help me with this please?

I already saw this post [Google Play Games - Leaderboard not displaying other players](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032200/google-play-games-leaderboard-not-displaying-other-players) but it didn't help me.